# Getting number of elements by using `element.all(by.id())`

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

I want to do something like this:

```js
it('should get number of API Key list'), () => {
    let numApiKeys = 0;
    element.all(by.id('ApiKeyList')).count().then(function(count) {
        numApiKeys = count;    // suppose count = 5
    });
    console.log(numApiKeys);   // but it shows numApiKeys = 0
});
```

I fail to get length of 'ApiKeyList'; `numApiKeys` always shows `0`.

How can I get actual length of the list?

Comment: Can you share a stackbiltz

Comment: Log the value of `count` inside the `.then()` clause. You will have access to it there.

Comment: @AdritaSharma Hi, thanks for your suggestion, I'm sorry but there're some difficulties in doing e2e configuration on stackblitz.

Comment: @tehbeardedone Yes, I can do that way, but actually I want do is getting number of elements outside `then()` scope ...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    let listCount = await element.all(by.id('radioApiKeyList')).count();
    console.log(listCount);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked by adding `async` declaration in the `it()` function.

Answer (score 0):

As Joaquin Casco mentioned, the following code worked:

```js
it('should get number of API Key list'), async () => {
    // suppose ApiKeyList have length of 5
    let numApiKeys = await element.all(by.id('ApiKeyList')).count();
    console.log('numApiKeys = ' + numApiKeys);   // numApiKeys = 5 
});
```

Comment: Just a quick tip: If you are using async/await in your tests from now on, you need to disable selenium_promise_manager in your config file. Seems like you were not using async/await when you posted this question.